# Compiler Error: Rust-cc and Cuda nvcc - "std::pair" is missing

Tags: rust, cuda

I'm trying to call CUDA C library from Rust. I am using the [cc crate](https://docs.rs/cc).

I get the following build error:

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
warning: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(460): error: argument list for class template "std::pair" is missing
warning: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(460): error: expected a ")"
warning: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(460): error: template parameter  "_T1" may not be redeclared in this scope
warning: /usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h(460): error: expected a ";"
warning: 4 errors detected in the compilation of "gpu/conv.cu".
```

My best guess is that NVCC is including headers from the GNU C++ compiler? I'm not sure how to remedy this?

My project directory structure is:

```
src/lib.rs
gpu/conv.cu
target
build.rs
```

The contents of build.rs is as follows:

```
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .cuda(true)
        .flag("-cudart=shared")
        .flag("-gencode").flag("arch=compute_52,code=sm_52")
        .file("gpu/conv.cu")
        .compile("libgpu.a");
}
```

The contents of lib.rs include:

```
#[link(name = "gpu", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    fn sum(x: *const f32, y: *const f32, out: *mut f32, count: libc::c_int);
}
```

This is the cc config printed by cargo:

```
Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `/home/james/code/mnist/target/release/build/mnist-58fd33a15ebff2d6/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
HOST_CXX = None
CXX = None
NVCC_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
NVCC_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
HOST_NVCC = None
NVCC = None
CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
CXXFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
running: "nvcc" "-ccbin=c++" "-Xcompiler" "-O3" "-Xcompiler" "-ffunction-sections" "-Xcompiler" "-fdata-sections" "-Xcompiler" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-Xcompiler" "-Wall""-"Xcompiler" "-Wextra" "-cudart=shared" "-gencode" "arch=compute_52,code=sm_52" "-o" "/home/james/code/mnist/target/release/build/mnist-74dea98666938639/out/gpu/conv.o" "-c" "gpu/conv.cu"
```

Comment: I would guess you are trying to use a gcc version that isn't supported with the CUDA toolkit you have installed. Yes it is normal that nvcc imports and parses the host compiler internal headers. And yes it is normal that if you use a non supported version it blows up exactly in the manner you describe in your question

Comment: Regarding GCC version not supported with CUDA toolkit. I've asked the question here - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267999 (if anybody is familiar with Arch Linux).

Comment: And yes, we see you have gcc 11, which is not supported by any version of the CUDA toolkit. The exact support configurations are explicitly described in the first few pages of the installation guide for linux, should you care to consult it

Answer (score 2):

Note this error can also occur when you instruct GCC compiler to NOT use its default C++ standard (e.g. for GCC 9.3, default C++ standard employed is C++ 14).

See https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-gcc-9-3-cuda-toolkit-11-3-not-a-supported-combination/193486/8